# setText элементов в CardView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, cardview

Есть `CardView` внутри `RecyclerView.`

При попытке сделать `setText` у одного из `TextView` внутри `CardView` вылетает ошибка.
**(Ошибочный метод):**

```
holder.managerPlan.setText(listData.get(position).getManagerPlan());
```

Если его закомментировать - приложение запустится без ошибок.

**Лог ошибки:**

```
07-11 09:37:22.221 3243-3243/ru.alexbykov.cardviewtest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: ru.alexbykov.cardviewtest, PID: 3243
                                                                     android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x64
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:52)
                                                                         at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4132)
                                                                         at ru.alexbykov.cardviewtest.ManagersListAdapter$override.onBindViewHolder(ManagersListAdapter.java:46)
                                                                         at ru.alexbykov.cardviewtest.ManagersListAdapter$override.access$dispatch(ManagersListAdapter.java)
                                                                         at ru.alexbykov.cardviewtest.ManagersListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ManagersListAdapter.java:0)
                                                                         at ru.alexbykov.cardviewtest.ManagersListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ManagersListAdapter.java:15)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5471)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5504)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4741)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2906)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3283)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreogra
```

**MainActivity:**

```
    package ru.alexbykov.cardviewtest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startFragment();
    }

    private void startFragment() {
        BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

**BlankFragment:**

```
 package ru.alexbykov.cardviewtest;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {


    View view;

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        initRecycler();
        return view;

    }

    private void initRecycler() {
        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        rv.setAdapter(new ManagersListAdapter(createManagers()));
    }

    private List<ManagersDTO> createManagers() {

        List<ManagersDTO> listManagers = new ArrayList<>();

        listManagers.add(new ManagersDTO("Alex Pavlov", 100));
        listManagers.add(new ManagersDTO("Ivan Pavlov", 95));
        listManagers.add(new ManagersDTO("Petr Pavlov", 75));
        listManagers.add(new ManagersDTO("Stepan Pavlov", 60));
        listManagers.add(new ManagersDTO("Azik Pavlov", 54));
        listManagers.add(new ManagersDTO("Azik Myand", 54));
        listManagers.add(new ManagersDTO("Azik Specca", 54));
        listManagers.add(new ManagersDTO("Azik Kane", 54));
        listManagers.add(new ManagersDTO("Azik McDonald", 54));
        listManagers.add(new ManagersDTO("Azik Jagr", 54));


        return listManagers;


    }

}
```

**ManagersDTO:**

```
package ru.alexbykov.cardviewtest;


public class ManagersDTO {


    String fullName;
    int managerPlan;




    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }



    public ManagersDTO(String fullName, int managerPlan) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.managerPlan=managerPlan;
    }


    public int getManagerPlan() {
        return managerPlan;
    }
}
```

**ManagersListAdapter:**

```
public class ManagersListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ManagersListAdapter.ManagersHolder> {




    private List<ManagersDTO> listData;

    public ManagersListAdapter(List<ManagersDTO> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
    }

    @Override
    public ManagersHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.manager_item, parent, false);


        return new ManagersHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ManagersHolder holder, int position) {



//        ManagersDTO item = listData.get(position);



        holder.managersName.setText(listData.get(position).getFullName());
        holder.managerPlan.setText(listData.get(position).getManagerPlan()); //Ошибка вот в этой строке




/*
        holder.managersName.setText(item.getFullName());
         holder.managerPlan.setText(item.getManagerPlan());*/

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }
```

**ManagersHolder**

```
 public static class ManagersHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView managerName;
        TextView managerPlan;
        CardView cardView;

        public ManagersHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


           cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);



            managerName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.managerName);
            managerPlan = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.managerPlan);
        }
    }


}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"

    tools:context="ru.alexbykov.cardviewtest.MainActivity">



</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_blank.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ru.alexbykov.cardviewtest.BlankFragment"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/recyclerView"

       />

</LinearLayout>
```

**manager_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

    >


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card:cardElevation="2dp"
        card:cardUseCompatPadding="true"


        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"


            >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/managerName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="8pt"
                />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/managerPlan"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="8pt"
                android:text="100%"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />


        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Не нужно весь проект выкладывать в вопрос) Достаточно было одной строки из логов с ошибкой и собственно строки, где она возникает)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Метод `getManagerPlan()` возвращает `int`, а у `TextView` нет метода `setText` который бы принимал `int`, вернее есть, но он принимает `resid`, поэтому у вас и ошибка такого вида:

> Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x64

Следовательно, надо либо возвращать `managerPlan` в виде строки `String`, либо же создать строку в onBindViewHolder так:

```
holder.managerPlan.setText(""+listData.get(position).getManagerPlan());
```

или так:

```
holder.managerPlan.setText(String.valueOf(listData.get(position).getManagerPlan()));
```

Comment: Получилось. Спасибо!

Comment: @nonews да не за что:)